# How much kayaking experience is needed for a trip on the Alabama Scenic River Trail?

Tags: kayaks, children

My family, including my 7 yo, are thinking about taking a week trip down the Alabama Scenic River Trail next year. What type of kayaking experience is needed for a trip like this? How can we benchmark if we are ready. We can take 1 day trip on local flat water rivers and lakes.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the entire trail is [631 miles long](https://www.nps.gov/WaterTrails/Trail/Info/30), so how much experience is needed will depend on where you go. The map does show some [Class 3 rapids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Scale_of_River_Difficulty) and portages (which are pretty miserable) but it does look like it would be possible to find an easy stretch of the river with no portages. The main resource that I  found for planning the trip is [here](http://www.alabamascenicrivertrail.com/trip-planner/).

As far as testing your readiness, I would suggest gradually increasing the length of trips.